# printing out question | how

Tags: support

I want print out a question with answers. But, when I push ctrl-P then I see few part of some answer cannot be printed out. How can I print all the question with all answers?

extra information:on ubuntu, unix

Comment: Exactly what parts can't be printed? What browser are you using?

Comment: @ChrisF, the browser is firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see it on the screen your browser should be able to print it - subject to any limitations of your browser. Does it have issues printing other web pages?

Check out [Stackprinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) which is an application written using the Stack Exchange API specifically for printing out questions and answers.